# Run raspberry pi 3b+ as router

Tags: raspbian, wifi, ethernet

I'm trying to setup my pi as router. And the graph down below is what I want to be.

```
 ________              _____________________
|        |            |                wlan1| >)) lan ((< Other device like smart phone
|Another |            |       Raspberry     |
|router  |>)) wan ((< |wlan0  Pi 3B+    eth0| >--lan--< My PC
|________|            |_____________________|
```

But now I can only done either wlan0 to eth0 or wlan0 to wlan1. How can I let pi share wlan0 to both wlan1 and ent0 at the same time.

I use Edimax N150 usb wifi dongle as a wlan1.

Comment: should eth0/wlan1 be on the same subnet? If so, you could bridge et0/wlan1 - then it's easy since its now bridge -> wlan0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Jaromanda X's comment.
So first I reference to [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a bridged wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-bridged.md) bridging eth0 & wlan1 as br0.
Then setup wlan0 connection by edit `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and install `dnsmasq` by using `sudo apt install dnsmasq`.  Modify `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` add following line below `interface br0`:

> static ip_address=192.168.220.1/24

After setting up `dhcpcd.conf`, we are now modifying `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` it's better to make a backup of the `dnsmasq.conf`. Now open up `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` add following lines:

> interface=br0
> dhcp-range=192.168.220.50,192.168.220.150,12h

Then enable ip_forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`, find `#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` and remove # beginning of it.
To make ip_forward enable immediately run:

> sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"

Adding iptable rules:

> sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o wlan0 -j ACCEPT

Then save rules:

> sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"

Appending new iptables rules in `/etc/rc.local`, so Pi will run it automatic every reboot. Open up `/etc/rc.local` appand `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` above `exit0`.

Finally start dnsmasq service and reboot system by following commands:

> sudo systemctl start dnsmasq.service
> sudo reboot